# Approximate inequality of factorial without numerical computing

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, factorial

I wonder which mathematical construct can be used to solve inequality of factorials. I'm studying computer science and I have always used numerical computing software as Wolframalpha to solve this.

Here is an example:

$$(365-n)! \geq 2,\quad n\in [1,365]$$

Comment: Is n supposed to be a natural number? Either way, I'd substitute $(365-n) = k$ and consider $k! \geq 2$, then work from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want $$m!\ge 2$$ then you need $m\ge 2$, since $2!=2$ and factorial is an increasing function.

Therefore you have the inequality $$365-n\ge2 \implies 1\le n\le 363$$

If there had been another number instead of $2$, say $r$ that is, if you have $$(f(n))!\ge r$$ Then you need to find a number $m$ such that $m!\ge r$ and then solve the inequality $$f(n) \ge m$$

Answer (score 0):

In this case, all you need to know is that the factorial is an increasing function for non-negative integers (i.e m>n implies that m!>n!).

So, since $2!\geq2$, we have that $k!\geq 2$ whenever $k\geq 2$. However, in your example, when n=365 or 364 we have 
$$(365-365)! = 0! = 1$$
$$(365-364)! = 1! = 1$$
So the inequality does not hold in the whole range. It does hold only for $n \in [1,363]$